# How can I append data without mutating state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a pagination system.
The reducer part looks like this:

```
(state, payload)=> {
            if (state.venues === null) {
                    state.venues = [];
            }
            state.venues.push.apply(state.venues, payload.data)
            return {
                    ...state,
                    isRequesting: false,
                    hasVenues: true,
                    venues: state.venues,
                    hasMessage: false
            }
    },
```

I iterate through `state.venues` in component.
The problem is, for the first request, `state.venues` is null so I should convert it to empty array to append payload to it.
But with this approach I think I mutate the state which is no allowed(recommend) in redux.
So how do can I achieve this without state mutation?

Answer (score 10):

To create a new array of venues use the spread operator:

```
var newVenues = [
    ...state.venues,
  'Tokyo'
];
```

You can use Object.assign to avoid mutating the state:

```
var newState = Object.assign({}, state, { venues: newVenues });
```

(I've left out the other parts of the state in your example for clarity).

Answer (score 3):

you can replace `push` with `concat`

concat is Array's **pure function** returns new array without mutating original values

```
  (state, payload) => {
    if (state.venues === null) {
      state.venues = [];
    }
    const newVenues = state.venues.concat(payload.data)
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: false,
      hasVenues: true,
      venues: newVenues,
      hasMessage: false
    }
  }
```

BTW:

if you find yourself repeatedly using Object spread or Object.assign in every sub-reducer / nested state. you should consider using [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this would be to append `state.venues` to `payload.data` and return `payload.data` as response.

```
            payload.data.push.apply(payload.data, state.venues)
            return {
                    ...state,
                    isRequesting: false,
                    hasVenues: true,
                    venues: payload.data,
                    hasMessage: false
            }
```